# How to delete a content type, programmatically?

Tags: nodes, 8

I programmatically created a **content type** during a module installation (using field storage configuration).

I want to delete that content type while **uninstalling** the module.

Is there any way to do this with Drupal 8?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just make sure that the node type depends on your your module, then Drupal will delete it automatically for you.

See node.type.book.yml in the book module for an example, this is the relevant part:

```
dependencies:
  enforced:
    module:
      - book
```

Note that users will have to delete all content of that type before they can uninstall the module then.

Comment: it seems to me that enforcing the module in node.type.custom.yml file is not sufficient to enforce the deletion of the nodes when uninstalling. `Note that users will have to delete all content of that type before they can uninstall the module then.` In my case the content type is deleted when uninstalling the module. But deletion of the custom content (nodes) is not enforced. To achieve this the custom module should implement `ModuleUninstallValidatorInterface`.

Comment: Drupal core's `book` module is a good example of how to make sure that a module may not be uninstalled if there is still related content. A `ProxyClass` is also required if copying Book's `services.yml` file. In that case the following command will be found useful:

`php core/scripts/generate-proxy-class.php 'Drupal\custom_module\CustomModuleUninstallValidator' "modules/custom/custom_module/src"`

Answer (score 11):

This seems to do it for me.

```
$content_type = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('node_type')->load('MACHINE_NAME_OF_TYPE');
$content_type->delete();
```

Comment: A CLI one-liner of this that uses Drupal Console with proper escaping is: `drupal snippet --code='$content_type = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage("node_type")->load("MACHINE_NAME_OF_TYPE"); $content_type->delete();'`

Answer (score 4):

To trigger some action upon uninstallation of a module you have to implement [`hook_uninstall`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21module.api.php/function/hook_uninstall/8.2.x) in your module's `*.install` file. Prior to deleting the content type you might want to ensure all nodes of that content type got deleted as well. Finally, after uninstalling the module and having the content type deleted don't forget to export the updated config.

```
/**
 * Place a short description here. 
 */
function MYMODULE_uninstall() {

  // Delete all nodes of given content type.
  $storage_handler = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
    ->getStorage('node');
  $nodes = $storage_handler->loadByProperties(['type' => 'MACHINE_NAME_OF_TYPE']);
  $storage_handler->delete($nodes);

  // Delete content type.
  $content_type = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
    ->getStorage('node_type')
    ->load('MACHINE_NAME_OF_TYPE');
  $content_type->delete();
}
```

Comment: Will this delete any `bundle` of `MACHINE_NAME_OF_TYPE`, like the [node-id query based answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/208159/93083) does, or not? I mean, that seems to be somewhat expensive (if there are a lot of NIDs) and I would like to use this solution when possible.

Comment: @Top-Master – I updated my answer. It needs an extra step to delete all nodes first.