# How to test if a config entity can be deleted?

Tags: 8, configuration

In my custom module are in hook_unistall all its config entities deleted. One of the entities causes after uninstall the following error:

> A non-existent config entity name returned by
>   FieldStorageConfigInterface::getBundles()

Is there some possibility to test, if the config entity is needed? I look for something like:

```
foreach ($configs as $config) {
  if (\Drupal::configFactory()->getEditable($config)->canBeDeleted()) {
    \Drupal::configFactory()->getEditable($config)->delete();
  }
}
```

I tried also to add the following lines in all configs:

```
dependencies:
  enforced:
    module:
      - svg_verzeichnis
```

After that works the uninstall in one module correct, but in another module I receive still the same error. In the error message is no info, which config is missing...

Comment: You should let Drupal do this automatically, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/195173/how-to-delete-a-content-type-programmatically

Comment: I will try it...

Comment: It looks like, it works. It is not quite optimal, because I can not automate the deinstallation of the configs, but it is probably the most stable solution. Thanks!

Comment: I have used it also by another module. I have there ca. 100 configs. After uninstall is the website dead. The error message: 'A non-existent config entity name returned by FieldStorageConfigInterface::getBundles()'

Comment: The problem is, that in the error message is no clue, which config is missing.