# How to delete content entity type programmatically on uninstall?

Tags: 8, configuration

I am trying to delete a configuration from a module in hook_uninstall.
My module creates a content type bundle which has to be deleted.
I tried to use an approach described here: [How to delete a content type, programmatically?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/195173/how-to-delete-a-content-type-programmatically)
but without luck, the content type still exists.

```
dependencies:
  enforced:
    module:
      - modulename
```

Of course, I delete entities of the given type before uninstall. Is there any way to do it programmatically: delete a content type with fields?

Comment: Did you tried 
  `$content_type = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
    ->getStorage('node_type')
    ->load('MACHINE_NAME_OF_TYPE');
  $content_type->delete();` 
in your `hook_uninstall` ?